# Идентификация экземпляра класса. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Возможно-ли создать несколько экземпляров класса и потом обратиться к ним по какому-то идентификатору кроме как с помощью добавления этих экземпляров в словарь или список?

Ну тоесть вот так получается:

```
from csv import DictReader

sched_file = open('schedule.csv')
schedule = DictReader(sched_file)


class Day:
    def __init__(self, w_day: dict):
        self.week_day = w_day['week_day']
        self.name = w_day['week_day_name']


days = {item['week_day']: Day(item) for item in schedule}

print(days['3'].name)

# Wednesday
```

А можно-ли как-то еще решить эту задачу?
В принципе, меня устроит ответ **"Нельзя"**, я успокоюсь и забуду эту тему ))

`schedule.csv`

```
"week_day","week_day_name","week_day_alt_name","les1","les2","les3","les4","les5","les6","les7","les8"
"1","Monday","Понедельник","Геометрия","Физкультура","Немецкий язык","Физика","Биология","Основы здоровья","Зарубежная литература",""
"2","Tuesday","Вторник","Химия","Английский язык","Украинский язык","Алгебра","Украинская литература","Информатика","Труды",""
"3","Wednesday","Среда","Немецкий язык","Мистецтво","Алгебра","Физика","Правознавство","География","Всемирная история","Физкультура"
"4","Thursday","Четверг","Английский язык","Алгебра","Химия","Зарубежная литература","Информатика","Всемирная история","Биология",""
"5","Friday","Пятница","Геометрия","Физкультура","Физика","Английский язык","Украинский язык","География","Украинская литература","Виховна година"
"6","Saturday","Суббота","","","","","","","",""
"7","Sunday","Воскресенье","","","","","","","",""
```

Comment: А приложите, пожалуйста, данные из `schedule`?

Comment: @gil9red. Добавил

Comment: Тогда, пожалуйста, можете привести желаемую альтернативу `print(days['3'].name)`

Comment: @andy.37 собственно вопрос и зключается в том, что-бы найти эту альтернативу. Знал-бы - не спрашивал.

Comment: Как вариант, можно написать класс, целиком читающий csv. Что-то типа `schedule = Schedule('schedule.csv')`. В нем определить `__getitem__/__call__`, и пользовать `schedule['wednesday']` или `schedule(3)`

Comment: @andy.37, Оформите плз в виде ответа, если не сложно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чуть упрощенный вариант без чтения csv

```
sched = (('1', 'Monday'), ('2', 'Tuesday'))


class Day:
    def __init__(self, row):
        self.id = int(row[0])
        self.name = row[1]

    def __str__(self):
        return '<{}: {}>'.format(self.id, self.name)


class Schedule:
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.items = {int(row[0]): Day(row) for row in lst}

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.items[index]

    def __call__(self, name):
        for _, item in self.items.items():
            if item.name == name:
                return item
        raise AttributeError('Wrong argument')

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self(name)


schedule = Schedule(sched)
print schedule[1]
print schedule('Tuesday')
print schedule.Tuesday
```

---

```
D:\Python\python.exe D:/PycharmProjects/tl/aa.py
<1: Monday>
<2: Tuesday>
<2: Tuesday>


Process finished with exit code 0
```

PS сорри за 2-й питон

Comment: Если добавить `def __getattr__(self, name): return self(name)`, то можно и так вызвать: `schedule.Tuesday`

Comment: @gil9red спасибо. Добавлю в ответ

Answer (score 2):

Можно сгенерировать переменные, но это странный способ - проще просто константами сделать.

```
...

class Day:
    def __init__(self, w_day: dict):
        self.week_day = w_day['week_day']
        self.name = w_day['week_day_name']


for item in schedule:
    day = Day(item)

    var = 'week_day_' + item['week_day']
    globals()[var] = day

    var = 'week_day_' + item['week_day_name']
    globals()[var] = day


print(week_day_3.name)          # Wednesday
print(week_day_Wednesday.name)  # Wednesday
print(week_day_Sunday.name)     # Sunday
```

Comment: Согласен, даже способ из вопроса со словарем (ну, можно списком) выглядит лучше.

Comment: Ну очень костыльный вариант, поскольку, как я понимаю, обращяться к таким переменным можно будет либо через овердофига if или через eval. Но спасибо за предложение. )

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать через поля класса сделать:

```
...

class Day:
    def __init__(self, w_day: dict):
        self.week_day = w_day['week_day']
        self.name = w_day['week_day_name']

        setattr(Day, 'WEEK_DAY_' + self.week_day, self)
        setattr(Day, 'WEEK_DAY_' + self.name, self)


for item in schedule:
    day = Day(item)


print(Day.WEEK_DAY_3.name)          # Wednesday
print(Day.WEEK_DAY_Wednesday.name)  # Wednesday
print(Day.WEEK_DAY_Sunday.name)     # Sunday
```